# Duplicating certain features based on symbol in QGIS Attribute table

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, fields-attributes, features, duplication

In QGIS 3.28.8 I have downloaded the data for power lines in different parts of Germany from OSM. Some of these lines and cables have different voltages (see below). I can filter those with several voltages quite easily.

[image: The current data that I have]

What I want to do next is to duplicate these features and have one per voltage. So to have two identical geometric features with one different attribute. I could duplicate the feature and then change the voltage attribute manually. The only issue is I have thousands of such power lines and cables, and this would take me a very long time.

Is there a way to do this automatically? I thought of maybe exporting the database and manipulating it in Excel or R, but I'd have to change the shape files concurrently to make sure the file is still readable.

Comment: Upload that layer to a PostgreSQL/PostGIS database and then you can easily manipulate your data spatial and alphanumerical there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the ["Split features by character"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html#split-features-by-character) tool from the Processing Toolbox (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>).

Sample dummy data, similar to yours as follows:

[image]

Below are the key parameters in the tool.

[image]

Here is the output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This saved me possibly several days of work.